# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - unwanted apps start after logging in

Tags: 16.04

Since past few days I am observing a strange behaviour when I login to my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. After I log in, Dolphin (the filemanager) automatically starts and the window is shown. I tried to search for any possible Dolphin startup into all the files in my home directory (that includes .local, .kde, and many others) but haven't found out from where this gets fired every time I log in.

Comment: P.S. I want to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Are you running Kubuntu? Vanilla Ubuntu doesn't have Dolphin.

Comment: Yes, I am using Kubuntu. I checked the solution pointed by @Terrance but that did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now solved. I went to "System settings" >> "Workspace" >> "Startup and Shutdown" >> "Desktop Session Login and Logout" and under "On Login", selected "Start with empty session". This fixed the issue.